# Signed in to Cognito with Amplify SDK, where is JWT?

Tags: jwt, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In my Vue application, I did

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
...
Vue.prototype.$Auth = Auth
```

in `main.js`, and then

```
const user = await this.$Auth.signIn(this.userInput.email, this.userInput.password) 
console.log(user)
```

in my login component. The console.log prints

[image]

Where is the JWT here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I hadn't created a new password yet. This is done with a

```
Auth.completeNewPassword(user, '<new-password>')
```

where `user` is the `CognitoUser` object returned from `Auth.signIn`.
After this, when doing `signIn` again, the `signInUserSession` field of the `CognitoUser` will contain the access token under `user.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken`.